# Show Frames of a Spritesheet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sprite-sheet

I don't have much C# experience, however I am writing a program to assist in modding another Game.  I wish to make a Form that allows you to preview frames of a Spritesheet.  Each frame is 16x32 pixels and the sheet can be no wider than 64pixels but can be as long as 4096px.  I have asked around with people I know and they have not been able to give me any place to start.  I have no code as I am unsure how to even begin. It requires no Animation just static images.

EDIT:  I am putting this on a WinForm. The small rectangle is all I need.

[image: Animation Station]

Comment: The place to start is System.Drawing.Bitmap assuming you are building for Windows (not cross-platform).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

You should be able to find examples online that you can modify to suit your purposes

Comment: it is a step in the right direction, it's samplecode shows how to do a whole image so I need to figure how to find out how to show only the 16x32 frame

Comment: Load the image into a Picturebox set to autosize. Put the pbox onto a Panel with autoscroll=true. . If you size the panel to a clientsize of 16x32  + the scrollbar width you are done

Comment: That's almost what I need, The intent is to allow the user to select a frame number and click to view it.. if it's the frame they want click another button to add the frame number to a list.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate everyone who answered quickly.  I was pointed in the right direction and I managed to build this code:
First I made this:

```
public Rectangle GetTileArea(int tileIndex, int tileWidth, int tileHeight, int sheetWidthInTiles)
{
    int x = tileIndex % sheetWidthInTiles;
    int y = tileIndex / sheetWidthInTiles;
    return new Rectangle(x * tileWidth, y * tileHeight, tileWidth, tileHeight);
}
```

Then all I had to do was:

```
private void seeFrame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Get Spritesheet
        image1 = new Bitmap(Environment.CurrentDirectory + $"\\Export\\[CP]{systemName}\\assets\\img\\spritesheet.png");
        Rectangle pixelAreaForTile = this.GetTileArea(tileIndex: (int)frameCount.Value, tileWidth: 16, tileHeight: 32, sheetWidthInTiles: 4);               // Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(xmin, ymin, xmaximum, ymaximum);
        Bitmap spriteFrame = image1.Clone(pixelAreaForTile, PixelFormat.DontCare);
        pictureBox1.Image = spriteFrame;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }

}
```